# Install and initialise google-cloud-cli in AWS CodeBuild buildspec.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I am trying to push docker container image built in AWS CodeBuild project to GCP Artifact Registry. In order to push image from AWS managed Ubuntu CodeBuild env, I will need to install and initialise google-cloud-cli. However, to authenticate/activate the CLI using a service account, it requires a service-account-key.json file containing the service account credentials as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.

I would like to avoid having to setup a EFS just to pass a json file to the build server. What is the best way to authenticate google-cloud-cli using a service account without having to use a json file?